# Extract text from image using pytesseract

Tags: python

I want to extract text from the following image using `Python`:

[image]

I tried with below codes but it's throwing an error:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
img=Image.open(r'gif file path')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract- 
OCR/tesseract'

r=pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(r)

And 

from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
img=Image.open('gif file path')
text=image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

Error:

> TesseractNotFoundError.

Please help any way to get the text using `Python`.

Note: `pytesseract` is already installed.

Comment: Are you sure you have added the right path to your tesseract.exe, pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract- 
OCR/tesseract.exe'. Double check the file exists in the path, add the right path to tesseract.exe.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is to have the library pytesseract installed, and other one is to have Tesseract installed.

If you are in Linux try:

```
sudo apt install libtesseract-dev tesseract-ocr
```